# Is it possible to create a parameter query in openoffice base?

Tags: openoffice-base

In access it is very easy to use it:
BETWEEN [minimum] AND [maximum]

But what is the syntax in openoffice base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  First is to have the query ask for user input.  Colons are used to indicate user-input parameters, like this:

```
BETWEEN :MINIMUM AND :MAXIMUM
```

Second is to use a one-row filter table.  Tie the user's form to this one row by making the form source something like `SELECT * FROM "Filter" WHERE "FilterID" = 1`.  Then the user will enter the dates into the filter table, and the query will have a join to the filter table to determine the dates.